# Haskell Recursion - finding largest difference between numbers in list

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion

Here's the problem at hand: I need to find the largest difference between adjacent numbers in a list using recursion. Take the following list for example: [1,2,5,6,7,9]. The largest difference between two adjacent numbers is 3 (between 2 and 5).

I know that recursion may not be the best solution, but I'm trying to improve my ability to use recursion in Haskell.

Here's the current code I currently have:

```
largestDiff (x:y:xs) = if (length (y:xs) > 1) then max((x-y), largestDiff (y:xs)) else 0
```

Basically - the list will keep getting shorter until it reaches 1 (i.e. no more numbers can be compared, then it returns 0). As 0 passes up the call stack, the max function is then used to implement a 'King of the Hill' type algorithm. Finally - at the end of the call stack, the largest number should be returned.

Trouble is, I'm getting an error in my code that I can't work around:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  t1 = (t0, t1) -> (t0, t1)
In the return type of a call of `largestDiff'
Probable cause: `largestDiff' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: largestDiff (y : xs)
In the first argument of `max', namely
  `((x - y), largestDiff (y : xs))'
```

Anyone have some words of wisdom to share?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone for your time - I ended up independently discovering a much simpler way after much trial and error.

```
largestDiff [] = error "List too small"
largestDiff [x] = error "List too small"
largestDiff [x,y] = abs(x-y)
largestDiff (x:y:xs) = max(abs(x-y)) (largestDiff (y:xs))
```

Thanks again, all!

Comment: by the way a more elegant solution could be `f x = zipWith (-) x (drop 1 x)` and `g x = foldl' max 0 $ map abs x` then your function is `h = g . f`

Answer (score 3):

So the reason why your code is throwing an error is because

```
max((x-y), largestDiff (y:xs))
```

In Haskell, you do not use parentheses around parameters and separate them by commas, the correct syntax is

```
max (x - y) (largestDiff (y:xs))
```

The syntax you used is getting parsed as

```
max ((x - y), largestDiff (y:xs))
```

Which looks like you're passing a tuple to `max`!

However, this does not solve the problem.  I always got `0` back.  Instead, I would recommend breaking up the problem into two functions.  You want to calculate the maximum of the difference, so first write a function to calculate the differences and then a function to calculate the maximum of those:

```
diffs :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
diffs [] = []                            -- No elements case
diffs [x] = []                           -- One element case
diffs (x:y:xs) = y - x : diffs (y:xs)    -- Two or more elements case

largestDiff :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a
largestDiff xs = maximum $ map abs $ diffs xs
```

Notice how I've pulled the recursion out into the simplest possible case.  We didn't need to calculate the maximum as we traversed the list; it's possible, just more complex.  Since Haskell has a handy built-in function for calculating the maximum of a list for us, we can also leverage that.  Our recursive function is clean and simple, and it is then combined with `maximum` to implement the desired `largestDiff`.  As an FYI, `diffs` is really just a function to compute the derivative of a list of numbers, it can be a very useful function for data processing.

**EDIT**: Needed `Ord` constraint on `largestDiff` and added in `map abs` before calculating maximum.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post for OP just as you answered, assuming the function naming mismatch was probably just a copy-paste-edit mistake

Comment: @jberryman I removed my reference to it, I also assumed it was a copy/paste mistake since I got the error he did after changing it to `largestDiff`.

Comment: @jberryman - thanks for noticing my syntax problem! I'm learning Haskell from an OOP background, so I make these mistakes all the time. Using the abs function after (x-y) fixes the 0 problem, but I'm still getting an off by one error (function isn't checking the last list element). However, I do agree that breaking down the problem into simpler pieces is the way to go - thanks for that tip!

Comment: @user2820683 What off by one error are you getting?  When I run `[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9]` through `diffs` I get `[1, 3, 1, 1, 2]`, which is 1 shorter than the input array as intended.  I also added `map abs` between `maximum` and `diffs` in `largestDiff` to compute the largest magnitude.

Comment: @user2820683 here's my current code: largestDiff (x:y:xs) = if length (y:xs) > 1 then max (abs(x-y)) (largestDiff (y:xs)) else 0.


Using the list [5,2,20,10] I get 18 - makes sense. Using the list [5,2,10,20] I get 8, when the answer should be 10. It's not comparing the last two elements in the list.

Comment: @user2820683 What happens if you pass in `[1, 2]`?  Follow the logic of your code: `largestDiff (1:2:[]) = if length (2:[]) > 1 then max (abs (1-2)) (largestDiff (2:[])) else 0`.  That should give you a hint at what is wrong here.  Maybe you should consider separating out your definition into difference pattern matching cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take at it.

First some helpers:

```
diff a b = abs(a-b)
pick a b = if a > b then a else b
```

Then the solution:

```
mdiff :: [Int] -> Int
mdiff [] = 0
mdiff [_] = 0
mdiff (a:b:xs) = pick (diff a b) (mdiff (b:xs))
```

You have to provide two closing clauses, because the sequence might have either even or odd number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem, which circumvents your error, can be obtained
by just transforming lists and folding/reducing them.

```
import Data.List (foldl')

diffs :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
diffs x = zipWith (-) x (drop 1 x)

absMax :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a
absMax x = foldl' max (fromInteger 0) (map abs x)
```

Now I admit this is a bit dense for a beginner, so I will explain the above.
The function `zipWith` transforms two given lists by using a binary function,
which is `(-)` in this case.

The second list we pass to `zipWith` is `drop 1 x`, which is just another way of
describing the tail of a list, but where `tail []` results in an error,
`drop 1 []` just yields the empty list. So `drop 1` is the "safer" choice.

So the first function calculates the adjacent differences.

The name of the second function suggests that it calculates the maximum absolute
value of a given list, which is only partly true, it results in "0" if passed an
empty list.

But how does this happen, reading from right to left, we see that `map abs`
transforms every list element to its absolute value, which is asserted by
the `Num a` constraint. Then the `foldl'`-function traverses the list and
accumulates the maximum of the previous accumulator and the current element of
the list traversal. Moreover I'd like to mention that `foldl'` is the "strict"
sister/brother of the `foldl`-function, where the latter is rarely of use,
because it tends to build up a bunch of unevaluated expressions called thunks.

So let's quit all this blah blah and see it in action ;-)

```
> let a = diffs [1..3] :: [Int]
>>> zipWith (-) [1,2,3] (drop 1 [1,2,3])
<=> zipWith (-) [1,2,3] [2,3]
<=> [1-2,2-3] -- zipWith stops at the end of the SHORTER list
<=> [-1,-1]

> b = absMax a
>>> foldl' max (fromInteger 0) (map abs [-1,-1])
-- fromInteger 0 is in this case is just 0 - interesting stuff only happens
-- for other numerical types
<=> foldl' max 0 (map abs [-1,-1])
<=> foldl' max 0 [1,1]
<=> foldl' max (max 0 1) [1]
<=> foldl' max 1 [1]
<=> foldl' max (max 1 1) []
<=> foldl' max 1 [] -- foldl' _ acc [] returns just the accumulator
<=> 1
```

Comment: That's a great answer: this is the most idiomatic Haskell way of doing it, and it comes with a good explanation.